# How to do a select with Zend Framework from a form?

Tags: forms, zend-framework, select, frameworks

im trying make a form with zend, and i do know how to do a select from a form

```
public function init()
{
    $this->addElement("text","titulo",array(
                      "label" => "Titulo"
                      ));
    $this->setAttrib("id", "enviarNoticia");
    $this->setAttrib("class", "FormEnviarNoticia");   
    $this->setMethod("post");
    $this->addElement("textarea","noticia",array());
    $this->addElement("submit","Enviar",array());
    $this->addElement("multiselect", "categories",array(
                        "label"     =>  "Categories",
                        "required"  =>  false,
                      ));
}
```

How to add options and item selected?

Comment: I don't exactly understand what is the problem and what you want to achieve. Can you please provide further information and extend your description?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to get the data from the form itself, you should get the data from the model/database in your controller and assign the values to the form from the controller.

```
// In a controller

// get the options from your model or database into an array
$options = array('name' => 'value', 'name2' => 'value2', 'name3' => 'value3');

$form = new Application_Form_Form();
$form->getElement('categories')->setMultiOptions($options); // set the $options as the options for the categories multiselect

if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if ($this->form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost())) {
        // form passed validation
    }
} else { // form was not submitted
    // to set default value(s) for the select
    $form->getElement('categories')->setValue(array('name2', 'name3'));
}
```